# Android resource lingking failed error while running in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am new at app development. My app is getting this error"android resource linking failed" at android studio. I have used java language. Can anyone help me to overcome this error? I am stuck.

I don't know how to approach to solve it.

Comment: plz read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  Share the errors and code here , we will sort it out